# Chance card in monopoly

Tags: monopoly

My piece was on Mayfair [Boardwalk in US version].  After moving, I passed GO and landed on the Chance along Kingcross station [Reading Railroad in US version].

The Chance card reads *"go to Pall Mall [St. Charles Place in US version] and if you pass GO collect £200 [$200 in US version]"*.

Can I collect £200 [$200 in US version] since I did pass go before landing on the chance space? What location is the Chance card concerned with?  My original space (Mayfair) or the current Chance space?

Comment: I've proposed an edit adding the US equivalents to this question, so that people who are familiar with the original version can understand your question better.

Comment: @Acccumulation - As long as you're doing that, I'll propose an edit to the currency too. It's been bugging me that this question talks about Mayfair and Pall Mall, but then mentions $200 rather than £200!

Answer (score 14):

The idea is, that you move clockwise (the normal direction) on the board until you reach your destination. If you passed Go, you collect the $200. If you did not pass Go, you did not collect $200.

In your case:

You are on Mayfair, rolled 8 and land on Chance. You passed Go, so you collect $200. Next the card sends you to Pall Mall. In this case, you did not pass Go, so you did not collect (another) $200.

[image]

And of course, you need to stop when you reach the destination for the first time (you can not go around the board several times to collect several times $200 ;-) ).

Comment: It is clearly written on the board : «COLLECT $200 SALARY AS YOU PASS GO», not «... AFTER YOU HAVE PASSED GO» (capitalised in the original).